# Android: Dynamically setting checkbox background

Tags: android, checkbox, view

I am trying to dynamically set the background color of a checkbox.  After Googling around I found the following:

```
checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_background);
```

but unfortunately, it only causes the checkbox background to disappear.

Any suggestions or comments would be helpful!

Below is the xml file being used as checkbox background:

**checkbox_background.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/off_white"/>
 </shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set size for the drawable

```
<shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

   <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
   <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/off_white"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the selector file in the drawable.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <item android:state_checked="true" 
           android:drawable="@drawable/check"\\ your drawable
           android:state_focused="false">
      </item>
      <item android:state_checked="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/check"\\your drawable
            android:state_focused="true">
      </item>
      <item android:state_checked="false" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/check"\\your drawable
            android:state_focused="false">
      </item>
      <item android:state_checked="false" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/check"\\your drawable
            android:state_focused="true">
      </item>
 </selector>
```

Add the following into your checkbox attribute.

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector"
```

let me know how it goes.

Comment: The text disappears and the checkbox doesn't change to the drawable specified :(